# Expose body to cold conditions

Tags: single-word-requests

Some people go to sauna and spend there a few minutes, this is believed to have a good effect on their health.

Similarly, some people go to swim for a few minutes in water with the temperature just above zero. Or they may wear only shorts in cold weather, have a cold shower, etc. What is the verb in English for practising this second kind of events?

Comment: Is there a word in any other language?

Comment: _Cryotherapy_ describes using this "cold immersion" to heal or prevent muscle soreness.

Comment: @jocap Yes, I could not find the translation of that word from Slovak to English.

Answer (score 1):

Informally, you could call this **taking a *Polar Bear plunge*** or **joining the *Polar Bear club***, even though many of these [*winter swimming* activities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_bear_plunge) are done more for celebratory reasons than for health benefits.

More formally, you could call this [cold water dousing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dousing).   From Wikipedia:

> **Dousing** is the practice of making something or someone wet by throwing liquid over them, e.g., by pouring water, generally cold, over oneself. A related practice is ice swimming. Some consider cold water dousing to be a form of asceticism.
>
> **Cold water dousing** is used to "shock" the body into a kind of fever. The body's reaction is similar to the mammalian diving reflex or possibly temperature biofeedback. Several meditative and awareness techniques seem to share similar effects .. Compare *cold water dousing* with *ice swimming*.
>
> The effects of dousing are usually more intense and longer lasting than just a cold shower. Ending a shower with cold water is an old naturopathic tradition. **There are those who believe that this fever is helpful in killing harmful bacteria and leaving the hardier beneficial bacteria in the body**. (emphasis added)

Answer (score 0):

There is no single verb, but you might say...

**"Proving to be hardy."**

hardy - courageous, intrepid, able to live through difficult conditions (such as a cold winter) [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hardy)

Comment: If you say without any context: "I often tend to prove to be hardy." Does that have the intended meaning of exposing your body to cold conditions?

Comment: @dt1510 No, not without context.

Comment: @dt1510 In addition to "cold resistant", "hardy" also means "bold", "brave" and "audacious".  But if you say that "apple trees are very hardy", anyone will understand you mean they can live through extremely cold winters.